# When I try to do errbot after errbot --init, I get the following error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, errbot

I can get errbot terminal as >>>. I am using python 3.5 and virtual enviroment is activated.

I am building a chatops bot for telegram. I was working on other device where errbot was fine but I can't even install it here. Can any one help me here ?

```
16:05:42 ERROR    errbot.cli                I cannot find the config file /home/roshan/Python/config.py 
(You can change this path with the -c parameter see --help)
16:05:42 INFO     errbot.cli                You can use the template /home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/cli.py/config-template.py as a base and copy it to /home/roshan/Python/config.py. 
You can then customize it.
(environment) roshan@roshan-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Python$ cd errbot
(environment) roshan@roshan-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Python/errbot$ errbot
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.cli                Config check passed...
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.cli                Selected backend 'Text'.
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.cli                Checking for '/home/roshan/Python/errbot/data'...
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma storage search paths {'/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage'}
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma Found those plugings available:
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma          Shelf  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/shelf.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma         Memory  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/memory.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.bootstrap          Found Storage plugin: 'Shelf'
Description: This is the storage plugin for the traditional shelf store for errbot.
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Refilter the plugins...
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/storage/memory.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Load the one remaining...
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Class to load ShelfStoragePlugin
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.storage            Opening storage 'repomgr'
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.storage.shelf      Open shelf storage /home/roshan/Python/errbot/data/repomgr.db
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.storage            Opening storage 'core'
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.storage.shelf      Open shelf storage /home/roshan/Python/errbot/data/core.db
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma backends search paths {'/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends'}
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma Found those plugings available:
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma            IRC  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/irc.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma           XMPP  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/xmpp.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma          Slack  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/slack.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma           Null  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/null.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma       Telegram  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/telegram_messenger.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma        Graphic  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/graphic.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma           Text  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/text.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma        Hipchat  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/hipchat.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.specific_plugin_ma           Test  (/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/test.py)
16:05:56 INFO     errbot.bootstrap          Found Backend plugin: 'Text'
                        Description: This is the text backend for Err.
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Refilter the plugins...
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/irc.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/xmpp.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/slack.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/null.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/telegram_messenger.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/graphic.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/hipchat.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 WARNING  yapsy                     Plugin candidate '/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/test.plug'  rejected by strategy 'SpecificBackendLocator'
16:05:56 DEBUG    errbot.specific_plugin_ma Load the one remaining...
16:05:56 ERROR    yapsy                     Unable to import plugin: /home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yapsy/PluginManager.py", line 488, in loadPlugins
    candidate_module = imp.load_module(plugin_module_name,plugin_file,candidate_filepath+".py",("py","r",imp.PY_SOURCE))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/text.py", line 16, in <module>
    from errbot.backends.test import TestPerson
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pytest
ImportError: No module named 'pytest'
16:05:56 ERROR    errbot.bootstrap          Unable to load or configure the backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/bootstrap.py", line 125, in setup_bot
    bot = backendpm.get_plugin_by_name(backend_name)
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/specific_plugin_manager.py", line 86, in get_plugin_by_name
    raise Exception('Error loading plugin %s:\nError:\n%s\n' % (name, formatted_error))
Exception: Error loading plugin Text:
Error:
<class 'ImportError'>:
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yapsy/PluginManager.py", line 488, in loadPlugins
    candidate_module = imp.load_module(plugin_module_name,plugin_file,candidate_filepath+".py",("py","r",imp.PY_SOURCE))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/text.py", line 16, in <module>
    from errbot.backends.test import TestPerson
  File "/home/roshan/Python/environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/errbot/backends/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pytest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [a bug in errbot](https://github.com/errbotio/errbot/issues/841) itself which affects the `Text` backend. What you can do to work around this until this is fixed upstream is to simply install [pytest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest/) in your virtualenv (through `pip install pytest`) so that the import succeeds.